# Error in initialising object with SIMD member using new keyword

Tags: c++, simd, avx

I was trying to initialise a C++ object with an SIMD member with a new keyword. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

class simd_obj {
protected:
    // float a;
    __m256 a;
public:
    simd_obj(float f) {
        // a = f;
        a = _mm256_set1_ps(f);
    }
};

int main() {
    simd_obj* a = new simd_obj(1.3);
    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled with g++ 5.3.0 with `-mavx` flag in windows 7 (via mingw). However, when it runs, it crashes.
When I changed the type of `a` into float and using a simple assignment (see the commented lines), it runs well, as expected.
Also, when I change the initialisation to `simd_obj a(1.3)`, it works, even with `__m256` type of `a`.

Do you have any idea why the code above does not work?

Comment: "it crashes" is there an output or error report that tells you why it crashed?

Comment: Assigning to `a` that way assumes it is 32-aligned, but `new` does not guarantee that.